# How to avoid error when there is no input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a simple class that takes input from the user. If the user just presses enter without entering any input, the whole application crashes. I have tried to solve the problem in many ways, but I failed.

The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterInput implements Input {

    public String input() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputString = scanner.nextLine().substring(0, 1);

        return inputString;
    }

}
```

And the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Range [0, 1) out of bounds for length 0
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:55)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:52)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:213)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:210)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:98)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckFromToIndex(Preconditions.java:112)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkFromToIndex(Preconditions.java:349)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4589)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2703)
        at LetterInput.input(LetterInput.java:7)
```

**Edit:**

I have tried to check whether the length of the inputString is greater that 0, before applying methods on it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterInput implements Input {

    public String input() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
        String outputString = " ";

        if (inputString.length() > 0) {
            outputString = inputString.substring(0, 1);
        }

        return outputString;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't immediately call `substring()` on the `String` returned by `nextLine()`. Instead, store the result of `nextLine()` and check it beforehand if the user entered valid input. Then react accordingly.

Comment: I have already tried that and I get the same error.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show the mentioned code which you tried.

Comment: The updated code you showed runs fine for me. If you still get an exception, please post the updated stacktrace and consider providing a [mre].

Comment: It works for me as well, when I create a minimal reproducible example, but it doesn't work on my initial project. I realised javac doesn't recompile this class when I make changes. How can I clear javac's buffer and make sure it will recompile all classes?

Comment: Thanks for  your help, I figured it out, instead of calling javac only on the main class I called javac *.java and now it all worked fine.